# What does leaves in three hours mean?

Tags: meaning

I was watching Subbed episode of Pokemon and stumbled upon this

> There's time to kill. They have missed the boat.The next one **leaves in three hours**.

Does 'leaves in three hours' mean the boat leaves after three hours or any time within three hours span?

Is it a sophisticated way of saying the former? Besides is it an American way or an English way?

Comment: _leaves in three hours_ means "leaves after three hours have passed". _leaves **within** three hours_ means "leaves sometime during the next three hours".

Answer (score 1):

"Leaves in three hours" means that the next boat won't leave until three full hours have elapsed. The use of 'in' here is somewhat misleading, and I can see why it could be confusing, but it is normal and proper usage when discussing time.